# Enhance this LINQ query for readability and performance?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I'm not the greatest with LINQ, but I'm trying to retrieve all the `ModuleAvailabilities` where the `academicYear` is the current year.

Are there any improvements to be made here?

```
pathway.PathwayFoundationModule.Attach(
    pathway.PathwayFoundationModule.CreateSourceQuery()
        .Include("Module")
        .Include("Module.ModuleAvailabilities.Location")
        .Where(o => o.Module.ModuleAvailabilities
                     .Where(x => x.AcademicYear == academicYear.Current)
                     .Count() >= 0)
);
```

Comment: You're saying when the `.Count() >= 0`, isn't it always >= 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean

```
pathway.PathwayFoundationModule.Attach(
            pathway.PathwayFoundationModule.CreateSourceQuery()
                .Include("Module")
                .Include("Module.ModuleAvailabilities.Location")
                .Where(o => o.Module.ModuleAvailabilities
                    .Any(x => x.AcademicYear == academicYear.Current));
```